# Does Laravel 5.2 support PHP 7.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7.2

I have project developed in Laravel 5.2 version. But now I want to upgrade only PHP version to 7.3 So can anyone let me know that if Laravel 5.2 works with PHP latest versions.

I want laravel version to be unchanged but with latest PHP version that is PHP 7.2+

Comment: you can it here.. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/composer.json .. But if you want to use 7.3 > .. laravel below 5.8 not support it.. there is syntax not supported for new php version

Comment: mean I can use php 7.2 with laravel 5.2. right?

Comment: As I don't want to upgrade my laravel version, I only want to get it working with php 7.2

Comment: I highly recommend to upgrade your Laravel version, as version 5.5 (LTS) will not get any security fixes after August 30th, 2020.
Let's imagine what bugs or security issues there may be in Laravel 5.2 (no security fixes after December 21st, 2016)...

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommend to upgrade your Laravel version in this case as Laravel 5.2 supports PHP version between `5.5.9 - 7.1.*` as per [documentation](http://PHP%20version%20between%205.5.9%20-%207.1.*) but if you have concerns you can tweak the php version to `7.2`  and test if its works.

To change the php version just add below code to your composer.json file.

```
"config": {

    "platform": {

        "php": "7.2"

    }

}
```

after that run `composer update` if you get any error you can always revert it back by tweaking the version again in `composer.json` file